# logical error in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my Code:

```
my_array_a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(my_array_a.flags.owndata)  # True
my_array_b = my_array_a[0:2]
print(my_array_b)                # [1 2]
print(my_array_b.flags.owndata)  # False
print(my_array_a is my_array_b)  # False
print(my_array_b is my_array_a)  # False
my_array_b = my_array_a[0:2].copy()
print(my_array_b)                 # [1 2]
print(my_array_b.flags.owndata)   # True
print(my_array_a is my_array_b)   # False
print(my_array_b is my_array_a)   # False
```

Question :
1. Line number 6 and 7 are showing me False . before i copy() on array.

```
print(my_array_a is my_array_b)  # False
print(my_array_b is my_array_a)  # False
```

Line number 11 and 12 are also showing me False.

```
print(my_array_a is my_array_b)  # False
print(my_array_b is my_array_a)  # False
```

Its confusing my understanding is line number 6 or 7 should show me True?

Comment: my_array_b=[1,2]   my_array_a=[1,2,3]  they are not the same.

Comment: "line number 6 or 7 should show me True?" - Why? If you tell us by what logic you arrived at your conclusion, it will be much easier to tell you where your error lies.

Comment: If you think "well, they have the same underlying data, so they're the same object", consider this: look out of one window and see a tree. Look out of another window on the same wall, and see the same tree. Are two windows actually _the same window_? The tree's what's the same. But you have _two different windows_.

Comment: Amadan you made my day by giving me such a nice example of tree and 2 windows .Many Many Thanks.

Comment: `my_array_b` is a different array object.  The fact that it is a `view`, sharing the data buffer with `my_array_a` doesn't change that.  `is` is a simple Python test for object identity, and doesn't do anything special in `numpy`.